# Authenticate on-prem application using Google Workload Federation Identity

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, on-premises-instances

We have a running application in an on-prem server. I would like to create an application which reads BigQuery table from GCP.

I have been restricted to use Service account key and that is not the best way of authenticate my application too right?

So googled and came to know about this "Google Workload Federation Identity".

But I am unaware that it asks for issuer URL and provider attributes which has be filled while creating.

[image: unknown fields]

Can anyone help me like, what is this issuer(URL) and how to get it?

So far I have created a workload Identity Pool.

Comment: Workload Identity Federation exchanges credentials from an identity provider for Google credentials. The URL is the endpoint for the identity provider (AWS, Azure, GitHub, etc.).

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley, I have seen like few peoples has deployed their code in github and used github issuer url according. But in my case the codes are setup in the server itself.

Answer (score 0):

Hello in very simple terms as I understand it Workload Identity Federation is just yet another abstraction on public/private key authentication/authorization.

Now let's say you have the target platform you want deploy resources to (VMs, storages, etc.) e.g. GCP.

And you have a source platform from where you want to deploy those resources e.g. Github actions.

The Github exposes the public key on public endpoint https://token.actions.githubusercontent.com/.well-known/jwks, the host is basically the issuer URL.

On GCP side you have to configure service account to trust the Github actions, there are two main components

- issuer - the URL of github actions to retrieve the public key
- subject - to identify unique repository from where you run github actions deployment

When configured and github actions want to perform the deployment it will request from GCP the authorization token for this particular service account to do the job.

The request contains the subject as well other information and is signed by Github **private** key. This means

- GCP can verify that the token request is really coming from Github by using the **public** key for verification exposed on that URL.
- You know that the github repo from which you are performing the deployment is really yours (because obviously you created it and configured the subject)
- The request cannot be falsified because no one else does not know the Github private key

So what this basically is, is a delegation of handling secrets (private key) to other service (Github) and you as a user of the service can go paswordless.

In case you have some e.g. on-prem application and you want to use this approach to authorize to GCP you have to handle this your self.

- exposing the publicly available issuer URL with public key
- managing your own private key
- defining subjects
- do the token request
- do the signing
- etc.

I guess there is some software that simplifies this process. But still it will be more effort than using some cloud native solution which do this for you.

Comment: Workload Identity Federation exchanges OIDC Identity Tokens from one Identity Provider to another. Implementing OAuth and OIDC is fairly complicated.